# update self lookup using pnp poweshell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I have a lookup column in my SharePoint online list. It is having a self lookup of the Yes/No column. my parent field is a Yes/No column and it is connected with a self lookup of another field in my same list. My source environment is SharePoint 2013, I have exported CSV data from these details. I am using PNP PowerShell to read the data from the CSV file move it into the online list. So how can I read the data from YEs/No column update it in the self look up the field in the same list?

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach ($Row in $CSVData)
{
    if($($Row.text))
    {
     $source_ID = Get-PnPListItem -List $List -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='fieldname'/><Value Type='Text'>$($Row.ID)</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>" | Select ID
     $itemID=$source_ID.Id

     Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $ItemID -Values @{internalname = $itemID} #updating self lookup
    }
}
```

Comment: I am checking some fields for an update, no need caml query all the item, just select the list item id and update in the look up field place